# Is vacuuming a PostgreSQL materialized view necessary?

Tags: postgresql, materialized-view, vacuum

I understand it makes sense to analyze a Materialized View (MV), but since MVs are not updateable, does that imply that we need not ever vacuum a MV?

Answer (score 6):

Materialized views need to be vacuumed:

1. At some point, old rows need to be [“frozen”](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/routine-vacuuming.html#VACUUM-FOR-WRAPAROUND) to prevent data loss when the transaction ID counter wraps around.
2. If you use `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY`, dead tuples are created and need to be removed by `VACUUM`.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz!  Man you are everywhere!